# VIM command or expression to select text from a function

Tags: vim, neovim

In my .vimrc file, I would like to configure a minimalist function to perform a smart selection.
For example try to select inner (), if selection is empty try inner [], if still empty try inner {}, etc.
But I am stuck at the very beginning: to call / execute a command / expression to select text from a function.

```
function! SelectInnerBrackets():
    " failed attempts
    call visualmode()
    execute "vi("
    execute "visual! i("
endfunction
```

Fyi: I actually use neovim, but it probably does not make difference to this issue.

EDIT: based on solution proposed by @Ingo Karkat, I share my final piece of code. Note that it does not work perfectly with cross nested delimiters.

```
function! SelectInner(delimiter)
    " We have to switch to normal mode to compare positions
    execute "normal! vi".a:delimiter."\<C-\>\<C-n>"
    return getpos("'<") != getpos("'>")
endfunction

function! TrySelectInner(delimiters)
    for delimiter in a:delimiters
        if SelectInner(delimiter)
            normal! gv
            break
        endif
    endfor
endfunction

" quickly select a word, expression or brackets content
nnoremap W viw
nnoremap E :call TrySelectInner(["'", '"'])<CR>
nnoremap R :call TrySelectInner(['(', '[', '{'])<CR>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read `:help visualmode()`, you'll notice that the (non-argument version of the) function is a query that has no side effects. Just `:call`ing doesn't do any good, and you don't need the current / previous visual mode, as you build the selection yourself.

Commands like `vi(` are *normal mode* commands. To invoke them from a Vimscript function, you need the `:normal!` command. `:execute` is used on Ex commands, in order to interpolate variable values (this is called `eval()` in many other languages), or use special `:help key-notation` (we'll use that later).

In order to test whether a selection was made, Vim conveniently has two special marks (`'<` and `'>`) that specify the boundaries of the selection. Unfortunately, they are only set after visual mode has been left (by operating on it, or via `<Esc>`). Within a plugin, it's better to use `<C-\><C-n>` keys instead of `<Esc>`; it will return to normal mode, too, but doesn't beep if we're already in normal mode. I use a separate `:normal!` command for that (with `:execute` to use the special key notation) to ensure that it will also execute when the previous command sequence aborts because no such selection can be made.

Taken together, here's the corrected version of your attempt:

```
function! SelectInnerBrackets()
    echomsg "trying (...)"
    normal! vi(
    execute "normal! \<C-\>\<C-n>"
    if getpos("'<") != getpos("'>") | return 1 | endif

    echomsg "trying [...]"
    normal! vi[
    execute "normal! \<C-\>\<C-n>"
    if getpos("'<") != getpos("'>") | return 1 | endif

    echomsg "trying {...}"
    normal! vi{
    execute "normal! \<C-\>\<C-n>"
    if getpos("'<") != getpos("'>") | return 1 | endif

    echomsg "nothing found"
    return 0
endfunction
```

In order to re-select, you can use `gv` afterwards, e.g. via this mapping:

```
nnoremap <Leader>V :if SelectInnerBrackets() <Bar> execute "normal! gv" <Bar> endif<CR>
```

Comment: I had to read it several times, but your answer is perfect! Thanks @Ingo Karkat (I am a bit sad that I have to leave visual mode to compare selection boundaries positions though)

Comment: Thanks! Glad I could help. You could alternatively also check the cursor position (`getpos('.')`, or just `col('.')`), but that would fail if you are at the end of the selection when triggering the mapping. Okay, you could fix that via `:help v_o` and checking again, but I think just leaving visual mode is easier. If you observe screen flickering, you could temporarily `:set lazyredraw` at the beginning of your function (and undo in a `:finally` block).